# select HQL with possible NULL Values

Tags: null, hql

I have a class Transaction.
Transaction have a Sender.
Sender have a field 'test'.
transaction.sender can be null or not.

I'm trying get all transactions whith sender = null or sender.test = true

I tried in HQL

```
select * from Transaction t where ((t.sender is null) or (t.sender.test is true))
select * from Transaction t where ((t.sender is null) or (t.sender.test in (true)))
select * from Transaction t where ((t.sender is null) or (t.sender.test = true))
```

and I'm getting only the transactions with 't.sender.test is true', I'm not getting the transactions with 't.sender is null'.

If I try only:

```
select * from Transaction t where t.sender is null
```

I get the the transactions with 't.sender is null'

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Edit:
My code is

```
StringBuilder q = new StringBuilder("from Transaction t where MONTH(t.dateTransfered) = :month and YEAR(t.dateTransfered) = :year ");
if (Val.required(request.getParameter("test"))){
        test = Boolean.valueOf(request.getParameter("test"));
        if (test){
            q.append("and ((t.sender is null) or (t.sender.test = true))");
        }
}
```

EDIT 2:

```
public List<Transaction> get(HttpServletRequest request, Date date, int start, int end) {

    StringBuilder q = new StringBuilder("from Transaction t where MONTH(t.dateTransfered) = :month and YEAR(t.dateTransfered) = :year ");

    if (Val.required(request.getParameter("niv")))
        q.append("and (t.sender.id = :niv or t.receiver.id = :niv) ");

    if (Val.required(request.getParameter("status")))
        q.append("and t.transactionStatus = :status ");

    if (Val.required(request.getParameter("serviceType")))
        q.append("and transactionServiceType = :serviceType ");

    if (Val.required(request.getParameter("source"))) {

        q.append("and transactionSource = :source ");

        if (Val.required(request.getParameter("sourceMethod"))) {
            q.append("and transactionSourceMethod = :sourceMethod ");
        }
    }

    boolean test = false;

    if (Val.required(request.getParameter("test"))){
        test = Boolean.valueOf(request.getParameter("test"));
        if (test){
            q.append("and ((t.sender is null) or (t.sender.test = true))");
        }
        else{
            q.append("and (t.sender.test = false and t.receiver.test = false)");
        }
    }
    else {
        q.append("and (t.sender.test = false and t.receiver.test = false)");
    }

    Query qry = entityManager.createQuery(q + " order by t.dateTransfered desc");

    qry.setParameter("month", DateUtil.getRealMonth(date));
    qry.setParameter("year", DateUtil.getYear(date));

    if (Val.required(request.getParameter("niv")))
        qry.setParameter("niv", Long.valueOf(request.getParameter("niv")));

    if (Val.required(request.getParameter("status")))
        qry.setParameter("status", TransactionStatus.valueOf(request.getParameter("status")));

    if (Val.required(request.getParameter("serviceType")))
        qry.setParameter("serviceType", TransactionServiceType.valueOf(request.getParameter("serviceType")));

    if (Val.required(request.getParameter("source"))) {

        qry.setParameter("source", TransactionSource.valueOf(request.getParameter("source")));

        if (Val.required(request.getParameter("sourceMethod"))) {
            qry.setParameter("sourceMethod", request.getParameter("sourceMethod"));
        }
    }




    qry.setFirstResult(start).setMaxResults(end);

    try {
        return (List<Transaction>) qry.getResultList();
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t.sender.test`creates an implicit inner join with sender. What you need here is a left join. `select *`, BTW, is SQL, not HQL. What you want is

```
select t from Transaction t 
left join t.sender s
where s.id is null or s.test = true
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I put the SQL code in my question but is really HQL. I edited my post and put my real code. I apreciate your answer. Can you help me to use you answer in my code? The SQL query its not fixed, I have a StringBuilder the add code according the parameters

Comment: I cant use left join in the query, there are a alternative to left join?

Comment: Why couldn't you use a left join? What prevents you from using it?

Comment: Look at my EDIT 2, there is no way to put left join in that code, there other comparisons in the query.